# defining a group by using the points of a parabola

Tags: finite-groups, cryptography

I'm trying to define an algebraic additive group on the
parabola $(x + 1)(x - 1)$ by using the well-known geometric
addition.

Given two points $P, Q$ on the parabola, I derived the equation of
line that insertects both points, then took a parallel line that
passes through the parabola vertex (0, -1), which is to be the
group identity, and intersected this line with the parabola to
get point which is the addition of $P, Q$.  This gave me the
following formula:

$$P(x_1, y_1) +  Q(x_2, y_2) = 
  \left(\frac{(y_2 - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)}, \frac{(y_2 - y_1)^2}{(x_2 - x_1)^2} - 1\right).$$

For adding $P + P$, I took the tangent at $P$, took a parallel line
to it that passes through the vertex (0, -1) and intersected it
with the parabola, getting the formula $P + P = (2x, 4x^2 - 1)$.

Taking a prime $p$, I expected to have a group reducing all points
modulo $p$, but something goes wrong.  For example, the point (0, -1) = (0, 4) mod 5 is the identity.  Trying to see if (1, 0) is a generator, I compute (1, 0) + (1, 0) = (2, 3).  Is (2, 3) on the parabola?  (2, 2^2 - 1).  It is.  Reduction modulo 5 here doesn't change the coordinates.  How about (1, 0) + (2, 3)?  It's (3, 8), but reducing it mod 5 yields (3, 3) which is not on the parabola.  (Maybe it is reducing the parabola itself modulo 5.)

Ignoring this possible problem, I see that (0, -1) = (0, 4) is not an identity.  For instance, (0,4) + (2, 3) = (4, 4).

How could I build such group properly?  Thank you.

Comment: How would your addition work when you are adding points of the form $(a,b)$ and $(-a,b)$?

Comment: Is this (group law) relation associative?

Comment: Are you asking how I'd add these two points?  These two are different points, then the addition would be $((b - b)/(-a -a), (b -b)^2/(-a -a)^2 - 1)) = (0/-2a, 0/(-2a)^2 - 1) = (0, -1)$, the identity.  This would mean that $(-a, b)$ is the inverse of $(a, b)$ and vice-versa.  Did I understand properly?

Comment: Why do you say that $(3,3)$ is not on the parabola modulo $5$? We have $3=3^2-1$ modulo $5$.

Comment: I meant it's not on the parabola x^2 - 1, but it is on x^2 - 1 modulo 5.

Comment: @T.Ingram, your last example: $(0,4)+(2,3)=(4,4)$ is wrong. It is $(2,3)$. My [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code is $\texttt{add(p,p1,p2)=my(x=p1[1]+p2[1]);[x,x^2-1]%p}$.

Comment: @Somos, after simplying the whole thing after Andreas Blass observation that some terms in the formula cancel each other out, it does follow that (0,4) is the identity.  But I think it should follow too without the simplication, so I must have some incorrect arithmetic going on somewhere and I haven't spotted yet.  Will look into this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, in your formula for $P(x_1,y_1)+Q(x_2,y_2)$, the first component $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ is just $x_2+x_1$, because, thanks to the equation $y=x^2-1$ of your parabola, the numerator $y_2-y_1$ equals ${x_2}^2-{x_1}^2=(x_2+x_1)(x_2-x_1)$.

So your addition operation for points on the parabola is just adding the first components (note that this also works when the two points are equal), and so your parabola group is just a copy of the additive group of real numbers.

The same thing happens modulo any prime.  To add two points, add their first coordinates to get the first coordinate of the answer, and then square that and subtract $1$ to get the second coordinate.

Comment: But this makes this group just addition modulo p --- with a decoration.  Not what I intended.  Did my addition formula not do justice to the geometric way of adding two points?  How is this done?

Comment: Your addition is quite reasonable, but parabolas (and, more generally conic section) are too similar to just a line, and so you get a trivial-looking addition.  That's why, for cryptographic purposes (which your tag indicates you're aiming for) one uses elliptic curves (cubic equations) rather than conics (quadratic equations). (That circles are also similar to lines is essentially because of the "tangent of half angle" expressions for the sine and cosine, familiar from integration tricks in calculus.)

Comment: I think you're saying I can't get a group that's not isomorphic to $Z_5$ by defining addition on the points of parabolas.  Is that correct?  Yes, I'm interested in cryptographic applications, so parabolas and all conic sections are actually not good for the purpose.  I must use elliptic curves or something else entirely.  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, working in $\mathbb Z/5$, parabolas will have just 5 points, and the only 5-element group is the cyclic one.  As for your more general question, I believe this is correct; I believe that all you'll get by geometric constructions from conic sections are the additive and multiplicative groups of the underlying field.

Comment: Thanks!  I now believe the same.  I derived the equation in all generality, so this well-known geometric procedure must not yield any profit on parabolas.

Comment: I think I'll ultimately take that back.  If we pick another parabola such as $x^2 - 2x$ with vertex at (1, -1) as the identity for the group, by using the usual geometric procedure for addition we get $P_1 + P_2 = (m + 1, (m + 1)^2 - 2(m + 1))$ as addition of different points where $m$ is the slope of the line along $P_1$ and $P_2$.  Notice that because m is in both coordinates of the result, this means it's not that same trivial addition we had before.

Comment: I could not define an addition for when $P_1 = P_2$ because apparently I get irrational points, but I'm looking into that.  Maybe picking another parabola.  It's clear though that the situation depends on the parabola.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = (x - 1)^2$ whose vertex is (1, 0).  Addition is defined as $P_1 + P_2 = (m + 1, m^2),$ where $m$ is the slope of the line over $P_1, P_2.$  If $P_1 = P_2$, then $P_1 + P_1 = (2x - 1, f(2x - 1)).$

Take prime $p = 5.$  The points modulo $p$ on this parabola are [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 9)].  The identity is (1, 0) and any non-identity element is a generator.

Comment: The problem I have now is that I'm not sure when I should reduce the coordinates modulo $p$.  For instance, consider the point (4, 9).  Reduced modulo $p = 5$, this point is (4, 4).  But (1, 0) + (4, 4) = (2, 1) when it should be (4, 4) because (1, 0) is the identity.  If I don't reduce (4, 9), it works: (1, 0) + (4, 9) = (4, 9).  (So I can say that at least reducing my $y$-coordinate modulo $p$ doesn't do what I want.  Maybe I should reduce only the $x$-coordinate.)

Comment: Reducing only the x-coordinate is no better.  I don't know what to do now to get closure.  Suppose I take a point such as (4, 9).  You can see we get closure if we do for example (4, 9) + (4, 9) = (7, 36) and only then we reduce it to (2, 1).  But if we reduce (4, 9) to (4, 4), we lose before we even try the addition.  Not sure how to get out of this.

Comment: I don't see where you got that (modulo 5) $(1,0)+(4,4)=(2,1)$ (modulo 5).

Comment: For the parabola $y=(x-1)^2$, the slope you called $m$ simplifies to $x_1+x_2-2$, so your formula for $P_1+P_2$ gives $(x_1+x_2-1,(x_1+x_2-2)^2$. So your addition formula amounts to the following: Add the $x_1-1$ and $x_2-1$ of the two summands to get the $x-1$ of the sum. In other words, your addition is isomorphic to ordinary addition, by having any point $(x,(x-1)^2)$ on your parabola correspond to the number $x-1$.

Comment: (I think I messed up in (1, 0) + (4, 4) = (2, 1).  Can't actually add with (4, 4) not in f(x).)

Okay, I didn't notice the simplification.  What was different this time?  I shifted the parabola a bit.  What if I rotate the parabola a little?  But I don't know how to rotate a parabola.  My intuition is that if by shifting on the x-axis I did cause a minor change in the addition, then by rotating it a little, the y-coordinate will have to play a part in the addition.  Does that make sense?  But I don't know how to rotate a parabola.  Can you see if that would achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Checked your remark.  Indeed, $m$ is nothing but $x_2 + x_1 - 2$.  My last hope is rotating the parabola.  I'm looking into how to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's why I was getting (1, 0) + (4, 4) = (2, 1).  I had not realized the simplification of the addition, so I was using the addition (m + 1 mod 5, f(m + 1) mod 5).  And this doesn't work for the points reduced modulo 5.  For instance, I actually get (2.3333..., 1.7777....) = (1,0) + (4,4).  It seems I either must not reduce the points modulo 5 or I must use your simplified addition.  Okay, I at least spotted the problem.  (But I don't get why there is a difference.  I *think* there shouldn't be.  Will look into it a little more.)

Comment: I don't know how to explain this.  If I don't simplify, I get nonsense.  (1, 0) + (4, 4) = (m + 1 mod 5, f(m + 1) mod 5) = ((4 - 0)/(4 - 1) + 1, ...) = (4/3 + 1, ...).  I certainly can't divide 4/3 because it's not an integer.  Should I compute 4 * 3^-1 mod 5?  That'd be 4 * 2 = 8 = 3 mod 5, not 4 as it should be.  So this is the problem I had.  I had not simplified and was getting nonsense and I don't know how to fix the nonsense.

Comment: Modulo $5$, the result of dividing $4$ by $3$ is $3$. You need to add $1$ according to your formula (where you wrote $4/3\ +\ 1$), so that gives $4$, as it should.

Comment: My + 1 was there but I totally missed it.  Thanks, Andreas!

Comment: My last challenge is to try a rotated parabola.  I got two formulas here, one parametric and another with y implicit.  Parametric: x = t cos(a) - t^2 sin(a), y = t sin(a) + t^2 cos(a).  Implicit: x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - sqrt(2)(y - x) = 0.  I'm looking for angles a in which both cos(a) and sin(a) are integers.  No such luck.  So I picked a = 45 degrees.  This rotates x^2 45 degrees counter-clockwise.  I find the points (0,0), (0, sqrt(2)), (sqrt(2), 3 sqrt(2)), (-3 sqrt(2), 6 sqrt(2)), (-6 sqrt(2), 10 sqrt(2)).  These are 5 points given by t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Instead of trying more and more parabolas, you would do well to study Somos's answer, which explains why your construction will not work better with one parabola than with another. Given any parabola in the plane, you can introduce a new coordinate system in which the parabola has the equation $y=x^2$. The change of coordinate system can only make the isomorphism to ordinary addition look more complicated; it cannot get rid of the isomorphism.

Comment: I understand that.  (I mean, Somos answer is advanced to my level, but I understand what you just said.)  It'd be a good achievement for me to find a group on this rotated parabola.  I understand this is of no use to cryptography.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that parabolas are affinely invariant. Given a parabola $P$, fix a point $P_0$. Given two other points $P_1,P_2$ on $P$, then the unique point $P_3$ on $P$ such that line $P_0P_3$ is parallel to line $P_1P_2$ defines an operation on points of $P$. The midpoints of the line segments $P_0P_3$ and $P_1P_2$ determine a line parallel to the axis of symmetry of $P$. Project the points $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ onto the directrix of $P$  using lines parallel to the axis of symmetry and denote them as $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3$ and note that $X_0+X_3=X_1+X_2.$
Introduce a coordinate system on the directrix, where $X_0$ is the origin. Denote the coordinates of the four points as $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ where $x_0=0$.  We get $x_3=x_1+x_2.$

This addition operation is similar in some ways to using the "prallelogram" law in affine geometry to add points. That is, given four points $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ that are vertices of a parallelogram, with $P_0P_3$ and $P_1P_2$ the two diagonals, then $P_0+P_3=P_1+P_2,$ except in this case, the diagonals bisect each other and thus, the two midpoints are the same point.

There are only a few simple geometric ways to "add points" and your operation is a new one to me.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what it means for a parabola to be affine invariant.  "Affine" seems related to parallelism.  Invariant is something that doesn't change.  I take it to mean that if I submit a parabola through an affine transformation, it comes out as a parabola still.  Is that it?

Comment: @T.Ingram Yes, that is what I meant. All parabolas in the affine plane are affinely equivalent. Same thing with non-degenerate triangles, parallelograms and so on.